# Copy Byte Array to Excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I am a little bit new to C#. The problem I am facing is that I need to copy a multi sheet excel retrieved as an byte array to another excel using C#. How it can be done?

Comment: What have you read/tried so far in this matter?

Comment: The problem is I am retieveing the excel as it is from the server side using the Http req as a bin file and finally i am pasting the content of sheet of retieved file to my existing file ,, Now in the case of multi sheet the sheet 1 retrieved at the client side contains the links to the sheet 2 ( DocumentMap) the sheet 1 wheer the links are present gets successfully gets pasted in my current workbook but the sheet 2 which has the actual data never gets pasted

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), a library for working with Excel from C#.

There are plenty of examples [here](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html).